# Rails ActiveRecord Postgres least and greatest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is there a preferred way to use greatest and lowest with ActiveRecord and Postgres?

I wanna get the min value of the 2 min queries. -> `LEAST(MIN(column1), MIN(column2))`

Here is an example what I wanna get in one query instead of 2.

```
cars = Car.joins(service_intervals: { 
  service_job: { service_note_jobs: :service_note } }
)
.where(id: id)

first_min_value = cars.minimum('service_notes.odometer - cars.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval'
secon_min_value = cars.minimum('cars.base_odometer - cars.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval')
result = [first_min_vlue, second_min_value].min
```

Comment: You mean the `MIN` and `MAX` [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/tutorial-agg.html)? Its very unclear what your actual desired result is though. If you can provide an example of the tables, the data and desired output then you can get actual answers.

Comment: Swipe to the right max. There is an `||` operator. So I wanna get the lower one of those 2 mins. Postgres has a LOWEST() and GREATEST() like this: https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/taking-maxmin-of-two-columns-in/

Comment: It's LEAST() not LOWEST().

Comment: Well, I think you need to write the select clause manually instead of using `ActiveRecord::Calculations`, its not really that useful for anything other than the most basic scenarios.

Comment: Something like `Car.joins(...).where(...).pluck('LEAST(MIN(service_notes.odometer - cars.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval), MIN(cars.base_odometer - cars.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval)')`

Comment: It works with that but turns out I need coalesce. So I only have to check the second value if the first one is null. For some reason though the following is not workin. Any ideas? `Car.joins(...).where(...).select('COALESCE(MIN(service_notes.odometer - cars.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval), MIN(cars.base_odometer - cars.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval)')`

Comment: It's working, just got confused by the logs that showed nil. Thanks!